# Android - load several images with Glide and display them all at the same time

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an image composed of three ImageViews (a character, his clothes, and his accessories) that i have to update a couple of times while the activity is in foreground. Each update consists in a specific set of images that are loaded in the corresponding ImageViews. All three ImageView must be updated exactly at the same time to avoid seeing the character moving before his clothes/accessories.

Using Glide, I tried to simply perform a sequence of usual calls

```
Glide.with(context).load(uri1).into(imageView1);
Glide.with(context).load(uri2).into(imageView2);
Glide.with(context).load(uri3).into(imageView3);
```

However, of course, each load is done asynchronously and therefore, the ImageViews updates are not simultaneous (and the lag is quite visible, even when the image files are loaded from the internal storage rather than over the network).

Is there a way with Glide to load all three images and only then update the ImageViews all at once ?

Answer (score 0):

That's what `Glide` is used for. To make a certain task perform asynchrously. You cant do it using `Glide` because that's how Glide is expected to behave. However, if you still want the same functionality, i suggest you do it by using `setImageResource` (or maybe find another way ...if even this is not the optimal solution for you) and not by `Glide`.